# How to remove all installed repository files and folders?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

I've tried before to install a repo called `flux` but I didn't manage to make it fully installed, and currently whenever I try to do `sudo apt update` i got a message says ***The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.***

I want to remove this package I've tried this command `sudo add-apt-repository -r http://ppa:launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux`  but it didn't work either, it says this repo doesn't have a release file.

I'm using `Ubuntu 21.10`

Comment: please update your question to say what release of Ubuntu are you on ...  20.04 or 18.04 ... or what ?  ... run this   `cat /etc/*release`    in a terminal and paste value of  VERSION

Comment: @ScottStensland I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /etc/apt

grep -r renniewaldock # do a search on any string in repo name
```

will show you the file containing that repository ... then edit that file

```
sudo  /etc/apt/the.file.found.in.above.grep.answer
```

you can simply comment out the line with that repo in that file to shut it off which will let you start over ... or just remove that file and any repository in it will be ignored

In general you want to stick to using the Ubuntu LTS releases ... those are ONLY even years and ONLY the .04  as in

```
18.04   bionic
20.04   focal
22.04   jammy
```

so in your case in above sudo vi /some.file   replace mention of

```
impish
```

with the name of the LTS release closest to your Ubuntu release

Since   21.10 is codenamed "Impish Indri"   then replace impish  with  jammy ... in below file

```
sudo  /etc/apt/the.file.found.in.above.grep.answer
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, can I simply just remove the file I found for this repo or it will cause any issues, PS. I don't need this package at all.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanGad yes you can just remove that file

Comment: Thank You very much scott, it works fine now